# Restore purchase using com.logicallabs.inappproducts

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

How do you restore a purchase using: com.logicallabs.inappproducts? I have been messing around with this all afternoon. I can purchase a product and restore it as if I were to buy it again, but can't figure out how to directly restore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get  a list of purchased products with this:

```
InAppProducts.addEventListener('receivedPurchases', function(e) {
   e.purchases.forEach(...
});
InAppProducts.getPurchases();
```

Then when you find the product you're trying to restore, execute the same code that calls when you purchase it.

Found in docs: http://docs.logicallabs.com/titanium-modules/in-app-products/android/modules/Readme.html

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing this also, it is straightforward.